# Not able to convert GPS coordinates received from a software into Latitude and Longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, coordinates, new-zealand

I am working on a software which returns GPS coordinates in this format:

Lat : '48684499'
Lon : '5203474'

I can not understand what type of coordinates are these and not able to convert them into proper Latitude and Longitude like :

Lat : '-41.295929'
Long : '174.77573'

Comment: Those coordinates look like they are in a Projected Coordinate System with units of metres or feet.  To identify which of many thousands of such coordinate systems it may come from can you tell us what part of the world the data comes from and what GIS software you are using?

Comment: Data is from New Zealand , and the software is 'VisiCAD'

Comment: I'd guess it was UTM Zone 48 South, but that's somewhere in indonesia, according to http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Utm-zones.jpg

Comment: For New Zealand, have a look at http://www.linz.govt.nz/geodetic/find-out/using-maps-with-projections. But I could not find any projection to match your first coordinates.

Comment: Is it possible we can get some more sample points, and where you expect them to turn up? Failing that, have you asked the OEM for the software for how points are supposed to be translated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

PROJ: https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/, http://proj.maptools.org/faq.html

Or the online tool: http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/

Hope this helps,